# Spring Boot ошибка: "Error creating bean..."

Tags: java, spring, rest, maven

Пишу проект по оценке книг. Падают тесты контроллеров Author, Book, BookRating. Все написано идентично предыдущим контроллерам, но вылетает ошибка Error creating bean. Пример ошибки для BookController:

`Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'bookController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'bookService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.chernoivan.books.rating.service.BookService' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}`

Все аннотации проверил, все на своих местах. Не могу понять в чем дело. Ссылка на Git с проектом: https://github.com/chernoivan/books-rating

### Код Book

```
@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)
public class Book {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private UUID id;
    private String title;
    private Double bookRating;
    private Date releaseDate;
    private String info;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private BookStatus bookStatus;

    @CreatedDate
    private Instant createdAt;

    @LastModifiedDate
    private Instant updatedAt;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "book", cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
    private List<Assessment> items;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "book", cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
    private List<BookGenre> bookGenres;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "authorBooks")
    private List<Author> authors = new ArrayList<>();

}
```

### Код BookRepository

```
@Repository
public interface BookRepository extends CrudRepository<Book, UUID> {
}
```

### Код BookService

```
@Service
public class BookService {

    @Autowired
    private BookRepository bookRepository;

    @Autowired
    private TranslationService translationService;

    public BookReadDTO getBook(UUID id) {
        Book book = getFilmRequired(id);
        return translationService.toRead(book);
    }

    public BookReadDTO createBook(BookCreateDTO create) {
        Book book = translationService.toEntity(create);

        book = bookRepository.save(book);
        return translationService.toRead(book);
    }

    public BookReadDTO patchBook(UUID id, BookPatchDTO patch) {
        Book book = getFilmRequired(id);

        translationService.patchEntity(patch, book);

        book = bookRepository.save(book);
        return translationService.toRead(book);
    }

    public BookReadDTO updateBook(UUID id, BookPutDTO put) {
        Book book = getFilmRequired(id);

        translationService.updateEntity(put, book);

        book = bookRepository.save(book);
        return translationService.toRead(book);
    }

    public void deleteBook(UUID id) {
        bookRepository.delete(getFilmRequired(id));
    }

    public Book getFilmRequired(UUID id) {
        return bookRepository.findById(id).orElseThrow(() ->
                new EntityNotFoundException(Book.class, id));
    }
}
```

### Код BookController

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("api/v1/books")
public class BookController {

    @Autowired
    private BookService bookService;

    @GetMapping("/{id}")
    public BookReadDTO getBook(@PathVariable UUID id) {
        return bookService.getBook(id);
    }

    @PutMapping("/{id}")
    public BookReadDTO putBook(@PathVariable UUID id, @RequestBody BookPutDTO put) {
        return bookService.updateBook(id, put);
    }

    @PostMapping
    public BookReadDTO createBook(@RequestBody BookCreateDTO create) {
        return bookService.createBook(create);
    }

    @PatchMapping("/{id}")
    public BookReadDTO patchBook(@PathVariable UUID id, @RequestBody BookPatchDTO patch) {
        return bookService.patchBook(id, patch);
    }

    @DeleteMapping("/{id}")
    public void deleteBook(@PathVariable UUID id) {
        bookService.deleteBook(id);
    }
}
```

### Код BookControllerTest

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@WebMvcTest(controllers = BookController.class)
@ActiveProfiles("test")
public class BookControllerTest {

    @Autowired
    private BookService bookService;

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mvc;

    @Test
    public void testDeleteBook() throws Exception {
        UUID id = UUID.randomUUID();

        mvc.perform(delete("/api/v1/books/{id}", id.toString())).andExpect(status().isOk());

        Mockito.verify(bookService).deleteBook(id);
    }
}
```

Comment: Попробуй инжектить бины через конструктор, а не через поле

Answer (score -1):

В *BookControllerTest* изменить `@Autowired` на `@MockBean` над объявлением `bookService`.